# How to defer sheet rendering until end of operation?

Tags: excel, ms-office, vba

I am using Excel to graphically examine embedded telemetry data. For this, I use the embedded software to dump memory arrays, in hex format, into text files. I then use Excel's "Text Import Wizard" to import the content of the file, using cut-and-paste.

In Excel, I use a VBA macro to convert the hex strings to decimal values, before manipulating and plotting them. For each source hex cell, I have an "image" cell containing the hex-to-dec translation formula.

The arrays are comprised of several hundreds, to a few thousands values. Thus, when importing/pasting the hex data on the "input" area, the "output" area is automatically calculated using the macro. The problem is that Excel refreshes the sheet (apparently) after each calculation. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/144151/274579) that resolves the update during the execution of a macro. However, my sheet does hundreds of *simple and short* calculations, so this is not effective.

**How can I prevent the update of the sheet until the end of the "paste" operation?** Note that I can disable auto-update allover. However, I do want to keep this option enabled, except for the specific text-import operation.

---

**UPDATE**: Here's the macro I use:

```
Type MyHex
Lng As Long
End Type
Type MySingle
sng As Single
End Type

Function Hex2Ieee754(i As Long)
Dim h As MyHex
Dim s As MySingle
h.Lng = i

LSet s = h
Hex2Ieee754 = s.sng

End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

Enclose your entire code into

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

' .... your code goes here


Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Do test your code thoroughly before doing this, though, because if it's going to take long to execute, the disabling of events would make your application unusable in the meanwhile.

**Update:**

The code's bottleneck is the way cells are updated, not the internal calculation itself. The following steps can be used to

1. fetch all values from the spreadsheet in a single operation and
2. push all calculated values to the spreadsheet in a single operation

Code:

```
Dim InputRng as Range
Set InputRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A10")

Dim InputVar() as Variant
InputVar = InputRng
' All data fetched in a single operation

'Now InputVar(1,1) contains the top left element of the range i.e. content of A1 cell

'You may use code such as

Dim LngVariable as Long
LngVariable = CLng(InputVar(1,1) + 23.232)
' etc.....

Dim OutputVar() as Variant
ReDim OutputVar(1 to 10, 1 to 1)    ' You need to output a range of 10 rows and 1 column
'Set elements of OutputVar to what you would like your Output range to be
' OutputVar(1,1) will be the top left element, etc.

Dim OutputRng as Range
Set OutputRng = ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B10")

OutputRng = OutputVar
' All data pushed onto sheet in a single operation
```

This code will be orders of magnitude faster than your original code. You may modify this to fit your program logic.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is what is suggested in the question I linked to. The problem is that it addresses the case where there is a single invocation of the macro, that covers all the desired cells. In my case, each cell triggers its own invocation. Think about a large table of numbers at `a1` to `a100`, and a 2nd table containing the `=abs(a1)` to `=abs(a100)` formulas. Now, replace `abs()` by `hex2dec()`.

Comment: ... this, unless the `Application.EnableEvents = False` makes the difference. Can you clarify?

Comment: Usually as you change the sheet, all sorts of events and subsequent actions could get triggered. Here, you are explicitly suppressing all event triggers till your code finishes its work. Doesn't always help, but won't hurt to try. Disabling events though, would make your code really hard to stop once it starts, so make sure there are no 'infinite loops' around

Comment: Well, it *seems* to be working, as it improved the update time of the sheet. I don't see why, though.

Comment: it's working because everything other than your code gets paused while you're running it. So it's on its own 'high speed lane' of sorts till it finishes. Also, in some situations, when you modify the sheet, unless events are disabled, I believe screenupdating proceeds on its own, even when disabled. So to suppress all such activity, you need to set `EnableEvents` to `False`

Comment: UPDATE: looks like this may not work after all. My previous assessment was based on artificially pasting large amount of "0" values on an area that already included mostly zeros. Excel seems to not run the macros on cells that were not actually changed. Once I pasted real data, the macro takes a long time to finish. However, I need to more carefully compare this case with the old macro form. It is possible that the old macro will take even longer to finish.

Comment: ah, perhaps if you could show a simplified version of your code in your question, there might be some solution for it

Comment: The function doesn't seem to be the bottleneck, how exactly are you pasting these values? is it cell by cell?

Comment: I believe that it is performed in a per-cell manner. I use Excel 2013's Text Import Wizard on a block of space-separated hex values copied from the text file.